# How to loop Button?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, android-button

I'm trying to display buttons. But the code below doesn't work. Apps has stopped unfortunately. Addtional code needed?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    String[] values = { "GOogle", "Yahoo", "Twi" };
    Button[] b = new Button[values.length];
    for (int i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
        b[i].setText(values[i]);
        layout.addView(b[i]);
    }
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: When You develop for android You read errors from LogCat not from emulator/device screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of your `Button` array are not instantiated before you attempt to call `setText` which will lead to an NPE. Try this

```
for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
   b[i] = new Button(this); // create Button programmatically
}
```

Also, in Java, arrays are zero based, replace

```
for (int i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
```

*Edit:* In this case both your `b` and `values` *happen* to be the same length so you could integrate the 2 loops together.

Comment: No error in source. When I run it on Anroid, the error is: "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Comment: What does it mean?:Also the elements of your Button array are not instantiated before you attempt to call setText

Comment: The `Button` array elements are still `null`. You need to assign value to them. See update

Comment: if findViewById() is used, i need to use already-built activity design. I want to design not in .xml but in code. Will it be possible in code?

Comment: Wow! It works. Maybe you're genius. You correct the error though you're not android deveoper. Thanks. :-) Happy.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liner);

```
    String[] values = { "GOogle", "Yahoo", "Twi" };

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(values[i]);
        layout.addView(button);
    }
```